# ViewPager and dynamic fragments : re-instaciation gives NPE

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I faced an issue with ViewPager and ViewPagerAdapter in Android.
I use a viewpager with 2 static fragments (one using a textEdit and the second one using a listview). Theyr are working pretty good.
But i have a problem with the third fragment which is dynamic.
It uses the camera and has to be instanciated, destroyed, re-instanciated following a scenario. So, the ViewPagerAdapter could contain 2 or 3 framents.
The problem appears when I re-instaciate the third fragment, I got a NPE after OnCreateView() (the main layout view is null after this method, but is not null inside the method).

There is the code for the main activity :

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager();
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

The setupViewPager() :

```
private void setupViewPager() {
    mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mTabFragmentDocument = new TabFragmentDocument();
    mTabFragmentDocument.setApp(this);
    mTabFragmentText = new TabFragmentText();
    mTabFragmentText.setApp(this);

    mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(mTabFragmentText, AbstractDefiner.TEXT);
    mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(mTabFragmentDocument, AbstractDefiner.DOCUMENT);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
}
```

To create the third fragment :

```
                mTabFragment = new TabFragment();
                mTabFragment .setApp(this);
                mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(mTabFragment, "THIRD");
                mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mTabFragment .setParams(tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3], tmp[4]);
                        mTabFragment .setupView();
                        mTabFragment .startWork();
                    }
                }, 1000);
```

And to destroy it :

```
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                mViewPager.removeViewAt(2);
                mTabFragment .onDestroy();
                mViewPagerAdapter.remove(2);
                mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mTabFragment = null;
```

Then, the Adapter code :

```
static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        mFragmentList.remove(index);
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Finally, the code of the third fragment :

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
    GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private static final String LOGCAT = "WEB_RTC_VISIO";

private HomeActivity mApp;
private String p1;
private String p2;
private String p3;
private String p4;

private VideoSource mLocalVideoSource;
private VideoRenderer.Callbacks mLocalRenderer;
private VideoRenderer.Callbacks mRemoteRenderer;
private GLSurfaceView mVideoView;
private SurfaceView mDrawView;
private SurfaceHolder mDrawHolder;
private ImageView mCursor;
private String mBgBytesString;
private ImageView mImgView;

private View mV;

public TabFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void setApp(HomeActivity app) {
    mApp = app;
}

public void setParams(String p1, String p2, String p3,
                      String p4) {
    this.p1= p1;
    this.p2= p2;
    this.p4= p4;
    this.p3= p3;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_layout, container, false);
    return mV;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}

public void setupView() {
    RequestUserPermission requestUserPermission = new RequestUserPermission(mApp);
    requestUserPermission.verifyStoragePermissions();
    mImgView = (ImageView) mV.findViewById(R.id.img_display); // NPE HERE
    TextView mTest1= (TextView) mV.findViewById(R.id.test1);
    mRequestLabelTextView.setText("test 1");
    TextView mTest2= (TextView) mV.findViewById(R.id.test2);
    mEquipmentSerialTextView.setText("test 2");
    // View that displays the view from the camera
    mVideoView = (GLSurfaceView) mV.findViewById(R.id.gl_surface);
    // View that displays the cursor and drawing associated
    mDrawView = (SurfaceView) mV.findViewById(R.id.draw_surface);
    mDrawHolder = mDrawView.getHolder();
    mDrawHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    mDrawHolder.addCallback(this);
    // Image of the cursor
    mCursor = (ImageView) mV.findViewById(R.id.mouseCursor);
    // Some more inits
}
public void startWork() {
//SOME WORK
}
}
```

So, the first instanciation is ok, but at the second, I got the NPE on getting the ImageView...
Someone can help me understanding this problem please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why are you destroying it?

Comment: Because I need to forbid to user to use the 3fragment when it's not necessary, and to free camera resources.
Then, for the future, i'll need to create 2 different fragments using camera, taking the place to the third fragment, depending of the situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` not `FragmentPagerAdapter` it will solve many problems. Hope it will gonna work for you too.

Comment: I tried, and it worked perfectly.
Many thanks, I didn't think that FragmentStatePagerAdapter was perfectly adapted to this kind of working ! 
Thanks !